# genymotion закрыли free personal?

Tags: android, genymotion

при старте эмулятора он пытается загрузиться, видна надпись `free personal only` и окно скрывается

в логах есть сообщение:

> [Genymotion Player] [warning] Activation failed. Error: 11 - "HTTP
>   code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error
>   downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server
>   replied: Forbidden"

при попытке получить лицензию сайт предлагает только платные версии:

https://www.genymotion.com/pricing-and-licensing/

free-редакция не доступна?

Comment: Лично я бесплатную пользую, там есть ньанс, после установки в один момент всплывает окно, там нужно выбрать `Personal use` по стандарту там галочка стоит что платную версию будете использовать, нужно переключить именно на `personal use`.

Comment: Вроде доступна https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/ после регистрации в фан-зоне. Могу предположить, что Ваш аккаунт удалён по причине длительного непосещения этой самой фан-зоны, либо фрее лицензия даётся на какой-то срок

Comment: `фан-зона` доступна, там и качал.  В заголовке окна `Genymotion for personal use`, как я понимаю это и есть персональная версия?

Comment: в about: `License type: Personal use`

Comment: На сайте регистрировались? Из письма по ссылке подтверждения переходили? В настройках программы логин и пароль указали?

Comment: Да. Запустился, после многократных переустановок. Значит проблем  не в лицензии была